# How to link to specific revision in Plunker

Tags: plunker

Here's an example of a plunker I wrote: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZudJcIak5sAWuiq3b1Hu?p=preview .

There are a couple versions available in the left pane, but they all appear to resolve to the same URL:

[image: screenshot]

How can I link to a specific revision?

Comment: That looks like it's not possible for now - the versions has a onClick handler which handles the behind-the-scenes-voodoo for fetching previous versions, no direct link

Comment: @Sathya, Good point, although that doesn't preclude an API that looks at a query parameter in the URL and makes the click for you after the page loads.